# How to write a Kusto query to select only the rows that have unique values in one field

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer

Having this input:

```
let t1 = datatable(id:string, col1:string, col2:string)
[
    '1', 'col1_1', 'col2_1',
    '2', 'col1_2', 'col2_2',
    '3', 'col1_3', 'col2_3',
    '4', 'col1_4', 'col2_4',
    '1', 'col1_1', 'col2_11',
];
t1 
| distinct id, col1
```

I need a query that will select only rows with unique values in "id" field. I understand that there are two possible outputs:

Output 1:

```
'1', 'col1_1', 'col2_1',
'2', 'col1_2', 'col2_2',
'3', 'col1_3', 'col2_3',
'4', 'col1_4', 'col2_4',
```

Output 2:

```
'2', 'col1_2', 'col2_2',
'3', 'col1_3', 'col2_3',
'4', 'col1_4', 'col2_4',
'1', 'col1_11', 'col2_11',
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make use of [any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/any-aggfunction) aggregate function to pick up the col1 and col2 values based on unique values in 'id' column.

```
let t1 = datatable(id:string, col1:string, col2:string)
[
    '1', 'col1_1', 'col2_1',
    '2', 'col1_2', 'col2_2',
    '3', 'col1_3', 'col2_3',
    '4', 'col1_4', 'col2_4',
    '1', 'col1_1', 'col2_11',
];
t1 
| summarize any(col1), any(col2) by id
```

Comment: Note that, if you want to ensure both values are chosen from the same record (e.g. `'col1_1', 'col2_1'` instead of `'col1_1', 'col2_11'`), you can use `any(col1, col2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for your needs?

```
let t1 = datatable(id:string, col1:string, col2:string)
[
    '1', 'col1_1', 'col2_1',
    '2', 'col1_2', 'col2_2',
    '3', 'col1_3', 'col2_3',
    '4', 'col1_4', 'col2_4',
    '1', 'col1_1', 'col2_11',
];
t1 
| summarize col1 = make_set( col1 ), col2 = make_set( col2 ) by id
```